# Pushing to TFS git using public/private key

Tags: git, tfs, public-key-encryption

I have a TFS server which is using git for source-control. How do I use ssh style public/private keys to push/pull/fetch from the TFS server? That is, where do I add my public key on the TFS server?

Comment: As far as I know, SSH for TFS 2013 / TF Service is not yet supported. I can't remember where I read it though (so I won't make this an answer), but I'm pretty sure someone said it was been worked on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per DaveShaw's comment, it's currently not supported as there is a Change request on the visual studio feedback portal.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3801342-add-support-for-ssh-keys-as-alternate-authenticati

Comment: Marked as resolved with TFS 2015 Update 3. They still seem to be lacking some documentation on the issue...

Answer (score 5):

TFS 2015 update 3 support SSH authentication, You can find the details in below link
 https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate

For TFS 2013 and TFS 2015 U1 and U2, you can connect to the TFS GIT repository by remotely by changing authentication settings like
Windows authentication : Disabled
Basic authentication : Enabled

Answer (score 0):

As saying by @abbottdev, there is **not** possible to public/private key, as far as I konw.

Besides, [Windows Credential Store](https://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/) is a tool which could be useful, (it seems to mean "**Once and for all**").

PS: It works also for *BitBucket*.

Good explication on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github/5343146#5343146).

Answer (score 0):

By using TFS 2015 update 3, you can connect the TFS-GIT repository remotely from GIT Installed Linux server using SSH authentication. For this you need to generate public and private key from Linux server by using SSH -keygen command. Then copy the public in TFS 2015.3 profile window. Then you can connect the TFS-GIT repository.

Answer (score -1):

Since git sends cmds and content through ssh, you could install openssh and a separate git client on the tfs server, cygwin is what i used, tfs wouldn't know the difference. You just would need to install openssh as a service. Although I did this with an Atlassian's bamboo server, the concept is the same.